# My excel output not coming as i wanted

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file-conversion

Helle guy,

I am trying to create a custom made excel output. But my thing is its not giving me output. Once the code reaches `if (fline.Designator == null)` its showing me an error.. 
Please have a look to my issue and give me a solution.

Codes:-

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);

        string line = string.Empty;
        string CarouselName = enter.Text;
        int iCarousel = 0;
        char seperator = '\t';

        SortedDictionary<string, ExcelData> lstExcel = new SortedDictionary<string, ExcelData>();
        ExcelData fline = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
        {
            line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[i]).Trim();
            if (line.Length == 0)
                continue;
            string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split(seperator);


            if (i > 0)
            {
                if (!lstExcel.ContainsKey(cells[1].Replace(" ", "_")))
                {
                    fline = new ExcelData();
                    lstExcel.Add(cells[1].Replace(" ", "_"), fline);
                    fline.Footprint = cells[2].Replace(" ", "_");
                    fline.Comment = cells[1].Replace(" ", "_");

                    iCarousel++;
                    if (iCarousel > 45)
                        iCarousel = 1;
                    fline.Location = CarouselName;
                }
                else
                {
                    fline = lstExcel[cells[1].Replace(" ", "_")];
                }
                fline.SrNo++;
                fline.Total++;
            }

            if (fline.Designator == null)// here its showing the error..
                // i don't know why its the code is incorrect. please help me out!!
                fline.Designator = new List<string>();
            fline.Designator.Add(cells[0].Replace(" ", "_"));

        }
        ExportInExcel(lstExcel, @"C:\Users\Stacy\Desktop\myExcel.xls");
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();

    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @grovesNL https://imageshack.com/i/f0tIFW6Dj Please have a lok to error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `for` loop, `fline` is never initialized.

Initially, there is a line:

```
ExcelData fline = null;
```

During your `for` loop, beginning at `int i=0` you have an `if (i > 0)` that assigns values to `fline` within that condition. However, for the case when `i=0`, `fline` is never assigned a value.

Therefore it follows that when you check if `fline.Designator == null` when `i=0` in your `for` loop, it throws an exception. The exception is telling you that `fline` has not been assigned an instance of `ExcelData`. In other words, `fline` is null itself: it doesn't have any property values.

I'm not sure *exactly* what your `if (i > 0)` condition is checking, but your solution is ultimately either:

- Changing `if (i > 0)` to `if (i >= 0)`, thereby handling the `i=0` case in your regular conditions, or...
- Instantiating `fline` at some point for the `i=0` case. You could do this when you initially declare the variable: `ExcelData fline = new ExcelData();` instead of `ExcelData fline = null;` (before your loop).

Comment: When i changed the i>0 to `i>=0` it worked perfectly.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your error is a null reference exception.
In your method you initialize `fline` with `null`:

```
ExcelData fline = null;
```

Then you enter a `for` loop and you start iterating from 0 (`int i = 0`).
You also have a conditio: `if (i > 0)` where you initialize the `fline` variable with an instance of `ExcelData` class:

```
fline = new ExcelData();
```

Note however that this happens only for `i` greater than 0.

So what happens when `i` is `0` - and that's the case during first iteration of the loop.
When you first iterate `i` is `0`. So you skip the `fline` initialization inside your `if` statement and you continue directly to

```
if (fline.Designator == null)
```

Here you try access `fline` but it's never been initialized. So you get null reference exception.